# '203: parsererror' at time of raising pull request on VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull

I am getting a '203: parsererror' on certain files at the time of raising a pull request on VSTS ? Has anyone had the same problem before and how was it resolved ? 
I can see the details of merge on some of the code files, but the 203 parse error is displayed on few others.
Thanks

Comment: Did this error happen when you clicking create button for pull request? Can you show the screen shot?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT : No the error was seen when I was reviewing the code files, **before** actually creating the pull request.Unfortunately I dont have the screenshot. Actually I have now resolved this problem. All I had to do was log out of VSTS and log in back again. This time the file contents were displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have now resolved this problem. All I had to do was log out of VSTS and log in back again. This time the file contents were displayed correctly.

Comment: You can mark (click √ symbol on the left the answer) your answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.